# Duplicate data within a single mysql table

Tags: mysql

'' 'Guys I need to duplicate the data of the table p_produto_loja, besides duplicating this data use the auto-increment to generate the id in the id column and finally put in the column fk_company = 1 to fk_company = 4, as I am now learning to manipulate the mysql, I need some help. '' '

```
Insert Into p_produto_loja (
  id,
  fk_produto,
  fk_company,
  fk_p_produto_aliquota,
  preco_custo,
  preco_venda,
  preco_v_atacado,
  qtd_estoque,
  margem_simples,
  margem_contribuicao,
  data_alteracao,
  data_validade,
  valor_adicional,
  qtd_minima
)
Select
  id,
  fk_produto,
  fk_company,
  fk_p_produto_aliquota,
  preco_custo,
  preco_venda,
  preco_v_atacado,
  qtd_estoque, 
  margem_simples,
  margem_contribuicao, 
  data_alteracao,
  data_validade,
  valor_adicional,
  qtd_minima,
  '4' As fk_company
From p_produto_loja
```

Comment: can you write the question in english?

Comment: In English please!

Comment: ok, is correct now, help please! @SebastianBrosch

Comment: ok, is correct now, help please! @Shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of columns and the order of columns should be the same in the INSERT and the SELECT clauses. Don't select `fk_company` since you want to hardcode it as `'4' As fk_company` - but do it in correct order. Don't list `id` column - just let the DB generate a new AUTO_INCREMENT value. The query should be

```
Insert Into p_produto_loja (
  fk_produto,
  fk_company,
  fk_p_produto_aliquota,
  preco_custo,
  preco_venda,
  preco_v_atacado,
  qtd_estoque,
  margem_simples,
  margem_contribuicao,
  data_alteracao,
  data_validade,
  valor_adicional,
  qtd_minima
)
Select
  fk_produto,
  '4' As fk_company,
  fk_p_produto_aliquota,
  preco_custo,
  preco_venda,
  preco_v_atacado,
  qtd_estoque,
  margem_simples,
  margem_contribuicao,
  data_alteracao,
  data_validade,
  valor_adicional,
  qtd_minima
From p_produto_loja
```

If you only want to duplicate the rows with `fk_company = 1`, then apend a WHERE clause:

```
Insert Into p_produto_loja (
   ...
)
Select
   ...
From p_produto_loja
Where fk_company = 1
```